# Deselecting all cells in a collectionView while changing the visual state

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uicollectionview

I have a block of code that should deselect all cells in a collection view (myHobbiesCV), while updating their visual state based on cellForItemAt (just an alpha change! nothing crazy.)

All of the selected cells are added into a string array called: myHobbiesArraySelected. When a button is pressed [Deselect All Hobbies], it should wipe out the myHobbieArraySelected array, and change all of the cells to the unselected visual state.

```
@IBAction func deselectAllPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let allSelected = myHobbiesCV.indexPathsForSelectedItems
    for deselect in allSelected! {
        print("deselected all")
        myHobbiesCV.deselectItem(at: deselect, animated: true)
        // This is essentially doing nothing :(
    }
    myHobbiesArraySelected.removeAll()
    print(myHobbiesArraySelected)
}
```

It's clearing out the array with removeAll, however the visual state of the cells are not changing at all.

**How can I change the cells visual state to unselected, along with wiping out the array?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about enumerate through all visible cells and change theirs appearance
 (If you want to deselect them anyway)?

```
for cell in collectionView.visibleCells {
    // Change alpha
}
```

Comment: Woo hoo! This works. Quick question - if my myHobbiesCV is 1,000 items long (it won't be... just for the sake of the question) - will visibleCells change the alpha state on all, even if they're not currently on the screen?

Comment: Well, you should read a little bit more about cells in collection view/table view : -) From technically point of view - cells in iOS are reusable which means - you always use the same bundle of cells, no matter how many times you scrolled. That's why you shouldn't save cells to array (the best option is to store theirs indexpaths). So if your logic in "cellForIndexPath" is correct, it should change visibility of all cells.

Comment: Cool! I'm not saving the indexPath because of the overall functionality of this profile setup section. Users can select multiple hobbies from multiple hobby categories, so it's been best determined to save the item itself.